# Saving one to one in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm just learning some `Laravel 9` and i'm doing a simple `one to one relationship` on two tables. I've created the relationships and the foreign keys which are working fine.

I am trying to create a new Hotel which saves info into the Hotels model and the facilities into the facilities model and are joined by the hotel_id as the foreign key.

I can't quite get my transaction right, where I have the hotel but need to pick up the id for it to pass and also have it as my foreign key on the facilities table.

```
 DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        $hotel = Hotel::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'address' => $request->input('address'),
            'postcode' => $request->input('postcode'),
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'star_rating' => $request->input('star_rating'),
        ]);

        $facility = HotelFacility::create([
            'hotel_id' => 39,
            'fitness_centre' => true,
            'bar' => false,
            'bar' => true,
            'parking' => true,
            'free_wifi' => true,
        ]);
        Hotel::find($hotel->id)->facility()->save($facility);
    });
```

Comment: @TimLewis I've updated question. I've just manully passed 39 for the moment as that's the next available id in my table

Comment: Fair enough; but you have the `id` available already via `$hotel->id`, so it seems odd  Converted comments to an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a few things you don't need to here.

1. When you call `create()`, it persists to the Database, so calling `->save()` later is redundant.
2. The last line is completely unnecessary as well.

There's ways to do this code by using relationship methods:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
  $hotel = Hotel::create([
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
    'address' => $request->input('address'),
    'postcode' => $request->input('postcode'),
    'state' => $request->input('state'),
    'star_rating' => $request->input('star_rating'),
  ]);

  $hotel->facility()->create([
    'fitness_centre' => true,
    'bar' => false,
    'parking' => true,
    'free_wifi' => true,
  ]);

  DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  DB::rollBack();
}
```